# A better way to phrase "Launch beta test"

Tags: meaning, grammar, american-english, sentence

I have a call to action button titled "Launch beta test".
However, I feel the wording is not proper.

I want to express to people that the product is still in experimentational mode, but is a close reflection of the final product. Any ideas?

I am just trying to be more convincing.

Comment: I understand *alpha* and *beta* tests have its own definition in a test stage of a game in order to check reactions of potential players. Why do you think *beta* is not proper? Because the development is almost completed? That means *beta* test has been already completed. No?

Comment: should i have both "beta and "test"

Comment: would there  be another way to word out beta test?

Comment: I really don't understand what you are asking.

Comment: allow me to clarify. 1) is it proper to use "beta" and "test" in the same line given that beta implies test. 2) would you using a different word other beta but meaning beta be more apprpriate\

Comment: Beta test / alpha test are broadly used terms. No problem using both at the same time. You need to be more concerned about the definition of beta test because it has an *extremely* specific definition.

Comment: 'beta test' is fine. It's an accepted term, so not sure what the problem is. If you want to imply that it's further along than beta, and just about to be released, you might use 'launch preview'.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. Last question. would it be better to use Launch beta test or Experience beta test?

Comment: 'Experience' vs 'Launch' would probably be better asked on a site dealing with interface design. Personally, I prefer 'experience'.

Comment: You may refer to "final validation steps", that is not really precise, generally encompassing "beta tests", "Factory acceptance tests" (FAT done in the dev team premices) and "Site acceptance tests" (SAT made on target environment).

Comment: "Inflict beta test"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well if it's a close representation of the final product you could use
"Launch a pre-release build"